# How to configure a custom code quality check in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, yaml

I'm trying to configure .NET project code quality check in GitLab Enterprise Edition 15.8.1-ee (Premium tier), but Gitlab UI doesn't show any code issue.

Since I'm going to use a custom code inspection tool (JetBrains Inspect Code command line tool), I've written a special converter that reformat JetBrains report format to Gitlab JSON format (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#implement-a-custom-tool). For testing purpose, I've prepared a GitLab code quality report, I added the report to the repository and added an additional Gitlab job to provide the file to CI pipeline.

Prepared GitLab code quality report (gl-code-quality-report.json) part:

```
[

    {
        "description":  "Using directive is not required by the code and can be safely removed",
        "fingerprint":  "a3d5c2a9-1761-4a18-8e17-35df9e2bc3a6",
        "severity":  "critical",
        "location":  {
                         "path":  "src/folder/Class.cs",
                         "lines":  {
                                       "begin":  8
                                   }
                     }
    }
    ...
]
```

.gitlab-ci.yml part (since the report is already pregenerated, powershell script do nothing):

```
check-code-quality:
  stage: check-code-quality
  only: ['branches']
  dependencies:
    - build
  script: ['powershell.exe .\build\check-code-quality.ps1']
  artifacts:
    when: always
    expire_in: 4 days
    reports:
      codequality: gl-code-quality-report.json
```

Current result: CI pipeline doesn't fail. The pipeline has a new job 'check-code-quality' and there is a new tab in the pipeline page - Code quality. Unfortunately, the tab has the text: "No code quality issues found.". In a merge request page there is a new section with the text "Code Quality hasn't changed.".

check-code-quality log has a text:

```
gl-code-quality-report.json: found 1 matching files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "codequality" to coordinator... ok  id=1684071 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_yasyB
```

Why I can't see any issue in Gitlab UI? Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found that my pre-generated file encoding is UTF-8 with BOM and it seems Gitlab doesn't recognize data with this encoding. When I change encoding to UTF-8 Gitlab shows the code quality widget and all issues described in provided JSON file.

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple things in mind.
First of all your **JSON structure** could be invalid. Make sure that the JSON file conforms to the GitLab JSON format as described in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html#implement-a-custom-tool).

Another problem could be that **location field** may be incorrect. It specifies the path to the file that contains the code quality issue. Make sure that the path is correct and accessible in your repository.

I would also check for the **artifact path**. Please verify that the path to the JSON file is specified in the *artifacts field* of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

In some cases it might also be related to a **cache issue**, try [clearing the cache](https://kp2.in.htwg-konstanz.de/git/help/ci/caching/index.md).

Comment: Well, I've provided example of JSON item and the example has the same structure as described in docs. I ensured that whole JSON has correct structure. Location field has file path relative to project root, checked as well. Artifact path correct as well, cause the provided log states that the file is found and uploaded as "codequality" to coordinator.